# Is it possible to get the WINAPI process handle by the process name without iterating through all processes

Tags: c++, windows

Good afternoon, Is it possible to get the WINAPI process handle by its name without walking through all the processes? 
I know how to WINAPI process handle by its name by iterating through all the processes:

```
     HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);      
     if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE){         
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)         
        {             
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, ProcessName ) == 0){                   
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);                  
                // measure process memory usage                
                CloseHandle(hProcess);             
            }         
        }     
      }      
      CloseHandle(snapshot);
```

However, it seems like it would take a significant amount of time to iterate through the process snapshot. Thank you.

Comment: Internally processes are maintained in a linked list, so ultimately somebody is going to have to iterate through them and compare the names.  I don't really see what your concerns are, though; a few hundred (at the most extreme) string comparisons is not going to take much time at all.

Comment: In C#, you can call GetProcessesByName? is there anything like it in unmanaged C++? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, there is nothing like that built into the Win32 API or any of the frameworks (ATL/MFC/etc) as far as I know.  You will just have to write it yourself; the code example you gave should be sufficient; GetProcessesByName() does something similar to that under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

Each process has a unique ID but not unique name. There could be multiple processes with the same name. So it is impossible, as it is impossible, for example, to get an entry from `std::map` by value w/o iterating trough everything. What you can do, however, is to write a function that gives you a list of IDs by name, that will be reusable, but still will have to iterate. Why do you worry about performance here? I believe it is nothing comparing to opening of the handle and process memory measurement.